# Setting UITableView FooterView after table reloading

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm making an app that as a UITableView that gets content from the web, parses it and shows it. It takes a little time to get it and parse it, so I use a loading indicator ([MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)) and do the loading in background. I wanted to add a button at the footer of the TableView, so I made up this code:

```cpp
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction)
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[myButton setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160.0, 40.0);
self.tableView.tableFooterView=myButton;
```

The proble is that it is initialized in the tableview during the ViewDidLoad() just after my background content loading code

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
    hud.labelText = @"Loading";
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        // Do something...
        [self getContent];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        });
    });
```

So when the view loads, the button is set on top (since the tableview is empty) and when it reloads, the button stays on top, I need to go to another view and come back to have the button in the footer.

Is there a way to set the button after the content loading ? Like a `-(void)tableViewDidReloadData` function ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you do it in the same call as `[self.tableView reloadData]` (which is a synchronous call) it'll display once the data is loaded.

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
hud.labelText = @"Loading";
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    // Do something...
    [self getContent];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [myButton setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160.0, 40.0)];
        [self.tableView setTableFooterView:myButton];
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually, it works but the button is empty and the title only appears when i tap it. Simulator bug ?

Comment: Yes, it did look fine but on the top of the tableview

Comment: As mentioned in the answer below, you should probably do it in the main thread - I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `[self.tableView reloadData];` only in the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
```

Comment: Because, the reloading operation as well as setting all kind of buttons, geometry and so on are GUI related operations that need to update the GUI and the main thread is for the GUI related stuff and operations that don't consume time. If you perform GUI related operation in another thread you will face unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create myButton and assign it to tableview footer in ViewDidLoad delegate instead of this create it at the time when you are hiding the MBProgress HUD and reloading the table

Try this it should work

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [myButton setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160.0, 40.0);
        self.tableView.tableFooterView=myButton;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
```